# Meaning of snobbishly

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adverbs

I'm reading *The Great Gatsby* and on the second page it says:

> As my father snobbishly suggested, and I snobbishly repeat a sense of the fundamental decencies is parcelled out unequally at birth.

I know a *snob* is a person who wishes to be seen as a member of the upper classes, but I do not know what *snobbishly* means.

Comment: [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snobbishly): "in a snobbish manner". [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snobbishly): "(pejorative) in a snobbish manner". [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/snobbishly): "in a snobbish manner, In the manner of a snob". And there are [at least 15 more dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=snobbishly&ls=a) that contain the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a standard noun-adjective-adverb construction.

A *snob* (noun) is *snobbish* (adjective), and behaves *snobbishly* (adverb).

same as:

A *child* (noun) is *childish* (adjective), and behaves *childishly* (adverb).